# ExportButton's resource attribute does not make any effect ( react-admin 3.7.1)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-admin

I have recently updated my `react-admin` version from `2.7` to `3.7.1`.
 Using `ExportButton`, i used to send an api call to the backend and my export `csv` used to get served from the backend.

The way i used to do it by manipulating the api call through the `ExportButton` `resource` prop. But since i have migrated to the newer version i saw there was no effect of passing anything to resource attribute, the url is getting generated by the default page's url.

I couldn't find anything regarding that new changes has been made to the ExportButton nor any issues stated on the github repo.

thanking you, in advance.

```js
const ListActions = ({ 
  resource, 
  filterValues, 
  total, 
  maxResults, 
  currentSort, 
  exporter, 
  permanentFilter, 
  showFilter, 
  displayedFilters, 
  filters,
}) => {
  return (
     <TopToolbar style={TopToolbarStyle}>
        {filters && cloneElement(filters, {
         resource,
         showFilter,
         displayedFilters,
         filterValues,
         context: 'button',
        })}
       <RefreshButton />
       <ExportButton
         disabled={total === 0}
         resource={resource + '_csv'} // used to changs page's url eg: page is home -> home_csv
         sort={currentSort}
         filter={{ ...filterValues, ...permanentFilter }}
         exporter={exporter}
         maxResults={maxResults}
       />
     </TopToolbar>
   )
};
```

Comment: At the point of destructing the `props`, how about you pass the custom `url` directly up there? Say, for example `const ListActions = ({ resource = 'home_csv', // ...other })`

Comment: actually the issue here is the resource attribute in the <ExportButton/> component , it does not takes any parameter passed to it.

Comment: Yes, I agree with you on the issue. But passing in a default above should work because that's typical `JavaScript`. Did you try it out?